# Add multiple items to cart while saving cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, magento2.3.5

I've run into a problem with my code when I try to add multiple items to my cart. I've added a product with the ID of 7 to the cart and then i'm trying to add a product with an ID of 8 to the cart, but instead it adds the product with ID 7 twice.

```
$params = array(
    'form_key' => $this->_formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => 8,
    'qty' => 1
);
    
$product = $this->_product->load(8);
$this->_cart->addProduct($product, $params);

$params = array(
    'form_key' => $this->_formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => 7,
    'qty' => 1
);

$product = $this->_product->load(7);
$this->_cart->addProduct($product, $params);

$this->_cart->save();
```

If I add another cart save between adding the two products, the next block of code is completely ignored currently.

Is there any way of getting around this or am I missing something?

Comment: You could use Magento rest API and achieve this using js

Comment: Theres a function called addProductsByIds($productIds), might this work? (\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\Cart.php).

Comment: I'm looking at how to do it through REST now and I will let you know. As for the addProductsByIds function, I think this works at a basic level. However, it loses the control of changing the product quantity as it doesn't have the parameters being passed to it

Comment: Within that function it references $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);... Might you need the getQuote in between adds?

Comment: I've tried adding the getQuote() and it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I'm going to carry on trying the API route for the moment